# How to Scan HBase Rows efficiently

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I need to write a MapReduce Job that Gets all rows in a given Date Range(say last one month). It would have been a cakewalk had My Row Key started with Date. But My frequent Hbase queries are on starting values of key.

My Row key is exactly **A|B|C|20120121|D** . Where combination of A/B/C along with date (in YearMonthDay format) makes a unique row ID.

My Hbase tables could have upto a few million rows. Should my Mapper read all the table and filter each row if it falls in given date range or Scan / Filter can help handling this situation?

Could someone suggest (or a snippet of code) a way to handle this situation in an effective manner?

Thanks
-Panks

Comment: Why don't you copy the contents of the table to a new one with the key rearranged and scrap the old one?

Comment: @Mario what if the table has a trillion keys? And he needs to do this often?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [RowFilter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RowFilter.html) with a [RegexStringComparator](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RegexStringComparator.html).  You'd need to come up with a RegEx that filters your dates appropriately.  [This page](http://sujee.net/tech/articles/hbase-map-reduce-freq-counter/) has an example that includes setting a Filter for a MapReduce scanner.

Comment: If Rowkey is handy, best performance is with Get. If returned result is too vast for a row, then Scan with get and batchSize is better/safer option.

Answer (score 11):

A RowFilter with a RegEx Filter would work, but would not be the most optimal solution. Alternatively you can try to use secondary indexes.

 One more solution is to try the [FuzzyRowFIlter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FuzzyRowFilter.html). A FuzzyRowFilter uses a kind of fast-forwarding, hence skipping many rows in the overall scan process and will thus be faster than a RowFilter Scan. You can read more about it [here](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/08/09/consider-using-fuzzyrowfilter-when-in-need-for-secondary-indexes-in-hbase/). 

 
Alternatively BloomFilters might also help depending on your schema. If your data is huge you should do a comparative analysis on secondary index and Bloom Filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the Scan that you send into the Mapper to include a filter. If your date is also the record timestamp, it's easy:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setTimeRange(minTime, maxTime);
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("mytable", scan, MyTableMapper.class, 
     OutputKey.class, OutputValue.class, job);
```

If the date in your row key is different, you'll have to add a filter to your scan. This filter can operate on a column or a row key. I think it's going to be messy with just the row key. If you put the date in a column, you can make a `FilterList` where all conditions must be true and use a `CompareOp.GREATER` and a `CompareOp.LESS`. Then use `scan.setFilter(filterList)` to add your filters to the scan.

Comment: setTimeRange filters on time stamp, not row key.

Answer (score -1):

I am just getting started with HBase, [bloom filters](http://www.quora.com/How-are-bloom-filters-used-in-HBase) might help.

Comment: Bloom filters wont help here unless he knows the exact key.

Comment: Thanks Chris - bloom filter stores the data digest instead of the actual data to make use of memory efficiently - so pattern matching shouldn't be possible.